# Is it possible to make Spring Boot JPA Hibernate application to automatically create tables with necessary columns and relations from JPA entities?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am a newbie that only knows basics of Java Core. I have test task where I need to create simple REST Web Service with Spring Boot.

I wrote all the logic in Java Core, and now I try to wrap it in all these technologies.

I am using this guide:

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/

Here they have JPA entities and @Table annotation, where table name is specified, but there are no SQL scripts to create tables in this guide.

So I thought JPA will create database and tables for entities by itself, but when I uncomment @Table annotation it says "Cannot resolve table '<table_name>'"

I am using IntelliJ IDEA with Spring Boot Maven project with imported Spring Web, H2 and JPA (like the guide tells to do).

I also configured H2 Data Source and tested the connection: works fine. There is a schema, but no tables.

Here is my application.properties:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2_console
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/kaylemains
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

As in the guide, I add entities in LoadDatabase class like this:

```
@Bean
CommandLineRunner initTournaments(TournamentRepository repository) {

    return args -> {
        log.info("Preloading " + repository.save(new Tournament("Kayle Mains Competition: Summoner's Gorge", 16)));
    };
}
```

So my question is: can I have file-stored H2 database and do everything with the it (including table creation) from my Java code?

OR it is necessary to create tables manually (by writing SQL scripts with CREATE TABLE) and construct them so that all entities work fine? (that means defining foreign key columns etc.), and only after that will JPA be able to work with this database? Do I need to add @Column annotation to every field, and JPA won't do it by itself for its Entities?

Why am I getting this error of "Cannot resolve table"? Of course it cannot be resolved because it does not exist yet, I thought JPA & Hibernate will create it for me based on entity classes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here in [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql) you have all the information about the properties to ddl generation

> Spring provides a JPA-specific property which Hibernate uses for DDL generation: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto.
>
> **create** – Hibernate first drops existing tables, then creates new tables
>
> **update** – the object model created based on the mappings (annotations or XML) >is compared with the existing schema, and then Hibernate updates the schema >according to the diff. It never deletes the existing tables or columns even if >they are no more required by the application
>
> **create-drop** – similar to create, with the addition that Hibernate will drop  >the database after all operations are completed. Typically used for unit testing
> validate – Hibernate only validates whether the tables and columns exist,  otherwise it throws an exception
>
> **none** – this value effectively turns off the DDL generation
>
> We have to set the value carefully or use one of the other mechanisms
> to initialize the database.

If the problem is still present go to  Settings -> Inspections, and uncheck the option "Unresolved database references in annotation"

Comment: I tried changing spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update to spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create, but it still says "Cannot resolve table"...

Comment: Check different things:

1 - Datasource is configured correctly?? You can configure the datasource also in the IDE //

2 - Settings -> Inspections and unchecking the option Unresolved database references in annotations

Comment: It actually created those tables and inserted rows from beans. I just needed to start Spring Boot application and wait a bit, lol.

So it works despite this "error" of "Cannot resolve table". It actually does create all these tables. All one needs to do is to start the app. :)

Comment: Yeah thanks man, disabling the "Unresolved database references in annotations" actually does solve this problem.